# Where can I find the js documentation

Tags: 2016

I'm looking for the documentation of the sp namespace. Especially Sp.Ribbon currently. 
I could only find the docs for Sharepoint 2010 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee557253(v%3Doffice.14)

Where are the docs for 2016 and 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint.

But note that the JavaScript Object Model (JSOM) is not supported in "modern-mode" sites in SP 2019.  So this documentation is good for SP 2013, 2016, and "classic-mode" 2019.

The link above is probably the closest thing you will find to a "complete" reference of SharePoint JavaScript. Oftentimes, searching sharepoint.stackexchange for a specific thing you are trying to do in JSOM will find you better resources that Microsoft's official docs. You can also adapt much of what is documented in the [CSOM reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee544361(v=office.15)), since the two API's work very similarly.

If you want to be as "future version compatible" as possible.  The recommended path for fully custom SharePoint development is using the [SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview), which is a full-fledged JavaScript framework extended from reactjs.  You can build solutions in [SPFx in SharePoint 2016, but only if you have at least Feature Pack 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support) installed.

Comment: Thank you for the link! 
I wonder though where I can find the complete reference, so a documentation of every Sharepoint js class, method and attribute, which I can use. 
Btw. if jsom is not supported anymore then, what is the alternative? And can the alternative also be used in 2016?

Comment: I editing my answer to include some additional information about JSOM references, as well as recommendations for building for future compatibility.